# Is the process on initialization of qubits unitary?

Tags: quantum-computer, unitarity

It is said in some texts, that quantum computer undergoes only `2` types of transofrmations:

1) unitary evolution while computing

and

2) non-unitary transformation while reading result (output).

What about input?

0) initializing qubits with values

Is it unitary or non-unitary?

Comment: That's the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics and extends beyond quantum computing. 0) and 2) are identical processes. So far we haven't found counterexamples. Interaction with the environment throws a couple of wrenches into this simplified picture, but we know how to work with those, too.

Comment: Since initialization destroys the previous value, it is not reversible and hence not unitary. The fact that unitary erasure of information is not possible (or the "no-erasure theorem") is the time-reversed counterpart of the famous no-cloning theorem. See http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v404/n6774/abs/404164a0.html and http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0375960103010478

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialization is non-unitary (at least if you don't know the state your qubits are in before that).  Let's say you want to initialize your qubits in the state $\lvert0\rangle$. First, you need to measure each qubit in some basis (say, $\{\lvert0\rangle,\lvert1\rangle\}$) -- this is the non-unitary part -- and now, if the result was $\lvert1\rangle$, you need to rotate $\lvert1\rangle$ to $\lvert0\rangle$ (which is unitary).